# How i can Send Session Data and Access it on view or Model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am new in Codeigniter, I creat an login form and now i want to pass some session variables to my view and my model but i failed

here is my controller code where i start session

```
function validate_credentials(){
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $query = $this->users_model->validate();
    if($query){
        $data = array(
            'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('site/dashboard');
    }
    else{
        //echo "Wrong";
        $this->index(); 
    }
}
```

**Here is my Model Code**

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{

    function _construct(){
        parrent::Controller();
        $this->is_logged_in();
    }

    function dashboard(){
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }

    function is_logged_in(){
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== true){
            echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login>Login</a>"';
            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**And Here Is my View Code where actually i want session variable**

```
<body>
<?php $session_id = $this->session->userdata('username');
echo $session_id;
 ?>
Members Area Olny...!!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "but i failed" mean? What did not work? How were results different than you expected? What, if any, errors messages did you get?

Comment: In `Site::_construct()` you call `parrent::Controller();` which (even without the typo of 'parrent') is incorrect. The line should be `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct.
Make sure that you have loaded the Session library in the autoload.php file in configuration folder.

- Codeigniter Porject folder

  - Application
  - Config

    - autoload.php

Open the autoload.php file and add session library

or

Copy and paste this code **$this->load->library(‘session’);** in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question properly but I think that you want to use the session data in the model.
ok for that you can use this code.

```
// To Set a Data in Session
$session_data = array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'is_logged_in' => TRUE      
    );      
$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $session_data); 

// To get the session data
 $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
 $user_name = $session_data['username'];
 $login_status = $session_data['is_logged_in'];
 //Now you can use this data in the model.
```

I hope I make it clear for you.